# How to modify Grid cells from a Frame Class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, wxpython

I'm trying to reset a grid table to its initial state after some modifications made on it (some texts added and background changed). My first thought was to do a ForceRefresh() but it didn't seem to work. After that, I thought that I just have to set background to white and SetCellValue to blank in order to simulate a refresh but it didn't work too.

When I use:

```
self.SetCellBackgroundColour(0, 16, "#ffffff")
```

I got this error:

```
AttributeError: 'TestFrame' object has no attribute 'SetCellBackgroundColour'
```

My main problem is how to modify something in my Grid from a Frame class. I'm sure that I'm not doing it right hence my question here.

I would appreciate if someone can help me solve my problem.

Here is the part of my code that is problematic (see the last def):

```
import wx
import wx.grid as gridlib

class SimpleGrid(gridlib.Grid): ##, mixins.GridAutoEditMixin):
    def __init__(self, parent, log):
        gridlib.Grid.__init__(self, parent, -1)

        [... Some Code to Create the grid]

class TestFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, log):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, 0, "Native Ads Reports V1.0", size=(1400,800))
        self.grid = SimpleGrid(self, log)

        # Create a status-Bar
        status = self.CreateStatusBar()

        # Create menu & Items
        menubar = wx.MenuBar()
        first = wx.Menu()
        applyItem = first.Append(wx.ID_ANY, "Apply Changes", "This apply all changes to the campaigns" )
        resetItem = first.Append(wx.ID_ANY, "Reset Changes", "This Reset all changes to the campaigns" )
        menubar.Append(first, "Action")
        self.SetMenuBar(menubar)

        # Associate a handler function with the EVT_MENU
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnApply, applyItem)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnReset, resetItem)

    def OnApply(self, event):
            """Apply all changes"""
            dlg = wx.MessageDialog(None, "Do you want to apply changes?",'Updater',wx.YES_NO | wx.ICON_QUESTION)
            result = dlg.ShowModal()
            if result == wx.ID_YES:
                self.count()
                from changeBid import changeBid
                changeBidTbBulk()

    #My problem is situated here. If the user clicks "Yes" in the dialog box the table should reset and all modifications should be deleted
    def OnReset(self, event):
            """Apply all changes"""
            dlg = wx.MessageDialog(None, "Do you want to reset all changes?",'Updater',wx.YES_NO | wx.ICON_QUESTION)
            result = dlg.ShowModal()
            if result == wx.ID_YES:
                db_conn.execute("DELETE FROM SandboxTB")
                db_conn.execute("DELETE FROM SandboxOB")
                db_conn.commit() 
                # Here I tried to change background
                self.SetCellBackgroundColour(0, 16, "#ffffff")
                #and here the refresh
                self.ForceRefresh()
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used self.grid.SetCellBackgroundColour and it worked.